# How to change form base url in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi Programatically i want to change from base url https into http

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>

// echo https://domain.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/5252/uenc/aHR0cDovL3RvdGFsdG95cy5jb20v/'
```

i want to change in

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>');" class="btn-remove"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a>

// echo http://domain.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/5252/uenc/aHR0cDovL3RvdGFsdG95cy5jb20v/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you just want to convert the anchor url from https to http?

Then you could do

```
<?php echo str_replace( 'https://', 'http://',$this->getDeleteUrl()) ?>
```

Changing the base url in the database programatically can also be done but it is probably a very **bad idea**.

Comment: How to check url have http:// or https because in my website have http:// & https:// also

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you need, why do you want to check if the url is http or https first?